# How to add fcm notification sound in app side

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

now my notification sounds are in server side

```
{
"to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
 "Nick" : "Mario",
 "body" : "great match!",
 "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
},
}
```

How to change it in app side (Locally java program for android or swift program for IOs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
```

put this code , when you want to play sound

Answer (score 0):

On Android -

1. First, you need to add your sound file into your project under `/main/res/raw/<file_name>`.
2. You can now reference the file using a URI like - `Uri notificationSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.packageName + "/" + R.raw.<file_name>)`
3. Next, you would have to handle an edge case for notification channels when you're working with Oreo and above. So this would look something like this -

```
   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       channel.setSound(notificationSoundUri,AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION).build())
   } else {
       notificationBuilder.setSound(notificationSoundUri)
   }
```

4. Finally - `NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(id, notificationBuilder.build())` should do the trick.

This is a cleaner approach since the user has a way to turn it off in notification settings.

On iOS -

You don't have to do anything fancy.

1. Add the sound file `.caf/.aiff` into your project and make sure it's under -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, if not add it.
2. The notification payload should have a `sound` param with the same name as you `.caf/.aiff` file. Which would look something like this -

```
   {
       "aps" : {
           "alert" : "You got your emails.",
           "badge" : 9,
           "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
       },
       "acme1" : "bar",
       "acme2" : 42
   }
```

More details here -https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Cheers & Happy coding!